# To show out of stock products on configurable products with multiple attributes?

Tags: php, magento-1.5, configurable-product

I want to show out of stock products in configurable product. I have done this successfully for configurable product with single attribute but not finding the way to do this when configurable product have two attributes

Comment: Please give a bit more details. How have you filtered the products when only using one attribute? Are you inside your own extension or where do you want to implement the code?